# Where to include index.yaml file in a war file

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, war

I have a java web application deployed on Google Compute Engine. I'm using Google Cloud Datastore to store the data. I'm fetching data using GQL query builder. I can retrieve data from the datastore as long as there is only one parameter involved. Simple queries like:

```
"SELECT * FROM logintracker WHERE logdate='2017-10-25' "
```

work fine for me. However, if I add some additional parameter like:

```
"SELECT * FROM logintracker WHERE logdate='2017-10-25' ORDER By logtime DESC"
```

don't work. I get a response saying that datastore needs developer-suplied index file. I did a bit of research and found that I need to specify my indexes in a index.yaml file. Here is my index.yaml file for that:

```
indexes:
- kind: logintracker  
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: logtime
    direction: desc
  - name: logdate
```

This is my question. Where should I include this index.yaml file in my application war file. Or is there any other location where I need to upload the index.yaml file directly on the server - like in cloud-storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your application which needs that information, it's the datastore itself. Which is why the index configuration is not specifically configured for the application, but instead directly uploaded to GCP (either by itself or together with the application, depending on the application type).

If you're using the datastore emulator, the file needs to be in a certain place. From [About index.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_About_index_yaml):

> The `index.yaml` is located in the `<project-directory>/WEB-INF/`
>   folder. By default, the data directory that contains
>   `WEB-INF/appengine-generated/index.yaml` is
>   `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/.` See [Cloud Datastore emulator
>   project directories](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#emulator_project_directories) for additional details.

As for uploading the file to GCP (i.e. updating the actual datastore indexes), from [The development workflow using the command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/#the_development_workflow_using_the_command-line_tool):

> The following is the typical workflow using the `gcloud` tool:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Upload the generated indexes with the [`create-indexes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/create-indexes) command, passing in the path to your local `index.yaml` file, as in
>      the following example:
>
>    ```
>    gcloud datastore create-indexes ~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml
>    ```
>
>    The example path assumes you have not set a specific directory for
>      the [`data-dir`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start#FLAGS) option. If you have set a specific directory,
>      modify the path to use the path to your `index.yaml` file.
>
> [...]
>
> 7. Over time, you might no longer use some of the indexes. You can delete unused indexes from your production Cloud Datastore instance by
>      removing them from your local `index.yaml` file and then invoking the
>      [`cleanup-indexes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/cleanup-indexes) command:
>
>    ```
>    gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes ~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml
>    ```
>
>    If you have set a specific directory for the [`data-dir`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start#FLAGS) option,
>      modify the path in the example to use the path to your `index.yaml`
>      file.

If you use a manually crafted an `index.yaml` file you need to specify the location of that file instead of `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml` in the `gcloud datastore` commands mentioned in the above quotes.

Comment: Thank you @DanCornilescu Just to add some additional information to your answer. I followed your process, but I had no idea how to check if my indexes were successfully added or not. Since I din't know this, I ended up creating multiple entries for the same index configuration. For future users, you can check your indexes in the "Indexes" option in Datastore. It also displays the status of each index configuration. Once the status reads "serving", you are ready to use your index.

Comment: Correct. I'ts mentioned on the page where my 1st reference exists.